# Strugling to understand complete predictive model process in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm very new to all this and I have a bit of a mental block on the logic of the process.  I am trying to predict customer churn using a database of current and already churned customers.  So far I have

1) Taken complete customer database of current customers and already churned customers along with customer service variables etc to use to predict on.
2) Split the data set randomly 70/30 into train and test
3) Using R, I have trained a random forest model to predict make predictions and then compared to the actual status using a confusion matrix.
4) I have ran that model using the test data to check accuracy for identifying the churners

I'm now a bit confused.  What I want to do now is take all of our current customers and predict which ones will churn.  Have I done this all wrong as alot of the current customers I need to predict if will churn have already been seen by the model as they appear in the training set?

Was I somehow supposed to use a training and test set that will not be part of the dataset I need to make predictions on?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have understood your question, I feel you want to know if you've done the right thing by using overlapping examples in your training and test set. You first need to understand that you need to keep your training set separate from your test set. Since your model parameters have been computed based on your training set, for similar examples in the test set, the model will give you the correct prediction, so your accuracy will definitely be positively impacted for those common training and test set examples but that is not the correct thing to do. Your test set should always contain previously unseen examples in order to properly evaluate the performance of your algorithm. 
If your current customers (on which you want to test your model) are already there in the training set, you would want to leave them out in the testing process. I'd suggest you perform a check between the training set customers and the current set of customers based on some unique identifier (if present) such as the Customer ID and leave common customers out of your fresh batch of unseen test examples.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. As mentioned on my other reply, I have kept the training and test set separate so far.  However because I have used all my 100k customer database either in test or train, Im not not sure how I predict on my customer database of current database because the model has already seen them during the model build and test phase? Was I supposed to take a much smaller sample to train and test? Many thanks

Comment: I think you can split your data into 3 sets then : training, cross-validation and test sets and you can keep your current customers in your test set after ensuring that those customers aren't in the training set. Although its better if you randomly split the dataset into the 3 subsets, you can still go ahead with this as long as there is no specific pattern in the behaviour of the current customers, i.e, their behaviour should be random.

Comment: Ok thanks but don't I need some current customers in my training and validation sets for the model to learn from? Which means the current customers I have put in my training or validation set I then can't get predictions on? Thanks again

Comment: If the current customers are just another set of customers with nothing extraordinary about them, then there is no such need to put them in the training set. You can treat them as the new batch of unseen examples your algorithm will predict on.

Comment: ahh ok, starting to make sense.  My last issue is though s that because I am predicting customer churn, dont I need to use some of the current i.e. customers still with us and some that have already left to train the model on.  That means the ones that are still with us who I have used for the training model I cannot use in the test and predict if they are likely to churn in future? Sorry if I'm missing something here, appreciate your help

Comment: and yes, there is nothing special about the customers I use for either train or test at the moment, just random sample from my complete customer database with the status 'current' or 'churned' along with predictor variables

Comment: Okay so you're right about the fact that you need to provide a representation of both kinds of customers in the training set : customers that are still with the company and customers that have left. I'd suggest you keep some customers who haven't yet attrited in the training set and keep the rest in the test set to test which customer is more likely to attrite.

Comment: ok, thanks makes sense.  I guess since I have alot more current than churn (about 85% to 15%) I can afford to keep alot more of the current customers out of the training and use for the test - this would also boost the churn to current ratio which could be a good thing? Does that make sense? I guess the question is if I have 85k of the 100k are current, how many do I actually use to train?  All very confusing :)

Comment: Yes it does make sense. You have a skewed dataset and ideally we would want equal representations of both classes in the training set but since you can't really help it, according to me, a 50k + 10k split in the training set and a 17.5k + 2.5k in the validation set and another 17.5k + 2.5k in the test set would help. But when you are checking for the performance of your algorithm, don't simply use the accuracy of prediction measure. Please use precision and recall and the F1 score.

Comment: ok got it, thanks v much.  One last question and then I'll mark this as the answer. on your numbers above, that means I can only get predictions that I can act on for 17.5k customers that are in the test set?  that's aot of customers I am not getting a prediction on?  I guess, if the variables change for the customers in the train set I can then use them in the test set.  For example if next month some of the customers I used in the train set all had a price increase, the data has now changed and I can use as a test set?

Comment: You will lose some customers to the test set from the training set but you can decide how much of your attrited customers you want to train on. Also, I don't think you can actually use the same customers in the test set just because of a change in one variable or feature unless it is a significant change. Actually, you shouldn't do this because the price change factor can be shown for the same customer by using an index such as a 'price sensitivity index' that shows how sensitive the customer is to price changes.

Comment: Excellent. really appreciate all that

Comment: Sorry, would you be able to see if this makes sense finally.  I have taken all my churned customers and randomly put 50% in train data set and 50% in test. I have then added a similar number of current customers to the train data set and kept the rest for the test data set.  What is the difference between testing the accuracy of the model to see if the predictions match the actual status and getting predictions for the at risk customers?

Comment: What do you mean by similar number of 'current' customers? Out of 100k, you've put 17.5k churned customers in the training set right? And how many current customers have you put in? 42.5k? If you've done that then it seems okay.

Comment: So when you test the accuracy of the predictions on the test set, you're basically testing to see if the predicted value provided by your algorithm matches the actual value (1 if the customer has attested, 0 if not). If there's a match then you just count the number of matches and divide it by the total number of observations in the test set. That's your accuracy. But it's better to look at precision and recall.

Comment: No I put about 9k churned and 15k current in to training as I wanted to keep as many back to make predictions on as possible.  So then I have 9k churned left for test.  If I add another 15k current for test set I have 50k current customers to run throuhg the model after testing to get predictions on? 15k + 9k test, 15k +9k train  - 50k current customers left to get predictions for?

Comment: In regards your last comment, I have been using precision and recall, just finally need to decide the above on the splits for datasets and how many customers to hold back to make predictions on?  Thanks again

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. All you need to ensure is that the proportion of churned and non-churned customers in both the training and test are the same. In your training set you have a proportion of 9/24 churned customers which is equal to the 9/24 churned customers in the test set. So that's fine. And yes you can proceed with your method of predicting on the current customers now.

Comment: dont apologise, you've helped alot today.  Think I have a plan.  Very last question, why is it so important to have the proportion the same in train and test set? Many thanks

Comment: It is important to have the same proportion in the train set more importantly so that your algorithm can train the same amount on both types of classes. Otherwise, say, you provide it with more current customers, it will only know how to recognize current customers better than the churned customers because it gets more current customers to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you have the standard training-test-validation set problem. If I understood correctly, you want to test the performance of your model (Random Forest) to all the data you have.

Standard classroom way to do this is indeed what you already did: Split the dataset for example 70% training and 30% test/validation set, train the model with training set and test with test set.

Better way to test (and predict for all of the data) is to use Cross-Validation to perform the analysis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)). One example for cross-validation is 10-fold cross-validation: You split your data to 10 equal size blocks, loop over all the blocks and for every iteration use the remaining 9 blocks to train your model and the test the model on the specific block.

What you end up with cross-validation is a more comprehensive knowledge of the performance of your model, as well as the results for all of the customers in your database. Cross-validation mitigates the errors in analysis due to random selection of the test set.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time on this.  I will look at the link you provided to get my head a round the cross validation.  However, I'm still not understanding something here. If my total customer set is 100k records and includes churned and current customers, how would I follow your approach.  At the moment I have used 70k of them to train and then 30k to test.  I guess the issue I have now is because I have used all my records either to test or train, I cannot now run just the current customers through the same model? I can try again if I am not making sense as I really need to understand

Comment: Hi, unfortunately as you've already trained your model with 70k customers, you can't use *that* specific model for cross-validation. If you use cross-validation, it means that you will have to train your model over and over again for each of the different training data set blocks (i.e. 10-fold cross-validation -> 10 different models). It can get quite computation heavy with large amounts of data. If you ran the same 70k (that you used to train the model with), you would get overly optimistic results (as your model is trained with those specific customers), thus cross-validation is better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply tele.  I'm no training with 50% churned customers and 50% current customers and only using 10k of the dataset.  This way I can use the rest of the current customers to run through the model to make predictions on.  Does this make sense?  Are there any guides on cross validation in R?  Finding it confusing in principle and how to run in R.  Many thanks